# For loop printing date twice in windows command

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am using windows batch command to save the cpu load at a particular time to a file named `cpu.csv`. I am using the following command

```
@for /f "skip=1" %p in ('wmic cpu get loadpercentage') do @echo %DATE%%TIME%,%p>>cpu.csv
```

Which works fine but gives double entry of date and time as below

```
4,Thu 06/23/201613:59:09.42
,Thu 06/23/201613:59:09.42
```

That means the load percentage got printed once only as required but the date got printed twice.

Comment: Probably the wmic command prints three lines of output?

Comment: Try with: `skip=2` :)

Comment: @drishti-ahuja You have used the wrong tah here in the question. Instead of `dos` use `cmd`.

Comment: @Rishav yeah its cmd

Answer (score 1):

Facts:

1. [`for /F` loop](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html): `SKIP` includes empty lines, but after the `SKIP` is complete, `FOR /F` *ignores* (does not iterate) empty lines;
2. `wmic` behaviour: each output line ends with `0x0D0D0A` (`<CR><CR><LF>`) instead of common `0x0D0A` (`<CR><LF>`); even *seemingly empty* trailing line contains `<CR>` in so far that it's not considered empty in `for /F` iteration.

**Solution #1**: nested loops

```
for /f "skip=1" %p in ('wmic cpu get loadpercentage') do @for %g in (%~p) do @echo %DATE%%TIME%,%g
```

Here the `for` loops are

- `%p` to retrieve the `loadpercentage` value;
- `%g` to remove the ending *carriage return* in the value returned.

See Dave Benham's [*`WMIC` and `FOR /F`: A fix for the trailing `<CR>` problem*](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4266)

**Solution #2**: force empty token instead of entire line:

```
for /f "tokens=2 skip=1" %p in ('wmic cpu get deviceID^, loadpercentage^, Status') do @echo %DATE%%TIME%,%p
```

Explanation:  the 2nd token

- *in a valid line* resolves to `loadpercentage` value (and trailing `<CR>` now belongs to ignored 3rd token);
- *in the `<CR>` line* is empty so that `for /F` loop would skip it.

**Edit**: added a batch file with complete [output redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) to a `.csv` file. Please note that `csv` separator is changed to `;` semicolon merely as `%time%` value contains `,` comma in my current locale:

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

rem                                       Solution #1
for /f "skip=1" %%p in ('
    wmic cpu get loadpercentage
                        ') do for %%g in (%%~p) do >>f38001801.csv echo %DATE%;%TIME%;%%g

>NUL 2>&1 timeout /T 2 /NOBREAK

rem                                       Solution #2
for /f "tokens=2 skip=1" %%p in ('
    wmic cpu get deviceID^, loadpercentage^, Status
                                 ') do >>s38001801.csv echo %DATE%;%TIME%;%%p
```

**Output** (

- output files erased for the sake of certainty;
- batch file run three times;
- output files typed

):

```
==> del *38001801.csv

==> d:\bat\so\38001801.bat

==> d:\bat\so\38001801.bat

==> d:\bat\so\38001801.bat

==> type *38001801.csv

f38001801.csv


24.06.2016;13:41:57,53;1
24.06.2016;13:42:19,10;11
24.06.2016;13:42:31,08;4

s38001801.csv


24.06.2016;13:42:00,11;1
24.06.2016;13:42:22,12;2
24.06.2016;13:42:34,13;1

==>
```

Comment: I tried your first solution, its working on command line but when I added `>>cpu.csv` to write the output to file it's not working. I tried doing the same making a `.bat` file but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Please keep in your mind that both **it's not working** and **still doesn't work** phrases do not explain your problem in any thinkable sense. See my edit.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the perfect batch file (Will not work if directly copied and pasted in cmd)

```
@echo off
for /f "skip=1" %%p in ('wmic cpu get loadpercentage') do (
    echo %DATE%%TIME%, %%p>>cpu.csv
    goto :break
)
:break
```

Use `pause` if necessary.

Comment: Not so perfect if loadpercentage is only one cipher between 0 and 9 (let's say `loadpercentage=2`): then [`>>` redirection](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) fails because of it would resolve to  `echo Thu 06/23/201613:59:09.42, 2>>cpu.csv` so that writes datetime to the console and nothing into `cpu.csv` as `STDERR` is   empty etc.

Comment: @Rishav your solution is printing the timestamp once which was desired but the value of load percentage is getting printed as %p and not the exact value.

Comment: @JosefZ is absolutely right, but that's not the only reason that is not quite perfect. Besides the terrible date/time output (derived from the question though), the returned line might still contain orphaned carriage-return characters (the *only* reliable and general method to ged rid of them is using two nested `for /F` loops!); and the date/time values do actually not belong to the CPU load, as the `wmic` query takes about a second or even more, but due to immediate expansion, date/time is taken *before* the `wmic` query has even started...